# why can this code not access 'borderWidth' (iphone code attached)

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, xcode4, calayer

why can this code not access 'borderWidth'  (iphone code attached)

This is based on a simple test project, but I did add QuartzCore framework however this didn't help.  Still is throwing the error, see code below.  Another project where I do this it works fine and I can't see the difference

```
#import "Customview.h"
@implementation Customview
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {

        // UI Layout
        self.layer.borderWidth = 5; // ERROR error: accessing unknown 'borderWidth' component of a property
    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add QuartzCore framework in order to access layer property of any UIView. Did you add that ?

Add Framework from following steps if you are using xCode 4

```
1. Select Target
2. Build Phases
3. Link Binary with Library Section
4. Tap + and find for the Quartz
5. Add Framework.
```

Now, Import it where ever you want to access layer property of any UIControl.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Also you need to *import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>*

Comment: yes I did do this (but it didn't help?) - went to Target => Build Phases => Link Binary with Libraries => added QuartzCore.framework.  Was there anything else I had to do?  You don't have to have any special "import" lines do you?

Comment: Yes Greg you need to write import statement I edited my answer check please.